# Sql Index Performance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a small table called "DataVisitorActivity" with this fields

```
id            int auto_increment primary key,
vID           int null,
category      varchar(128) null,
timestamp     timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
value         text null,
handle        text null
```

it have 2 index fields

```
handle_index(handle)
DataVisitorActivity_vID_index(vID)
```

Until now I had no performance problems all worked in around 0.01 seconds.
currently the table have around 2Milion entrys and it will get bigger every day (We save every website the user visits in this list) 
The only thing I had to change last time I edit the table was to set "handle" to "text" because we have really long strings that get saved in that field. 
with that change the query I use

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS `blog_count`, handle FROM  DataVisitorActivity WHERE value = "blog" GROUP BY handle ORDER BY blog_count DESC Limit 5
```

this time it needs 0.1 - 0.3 seconds still fine for me.

I saw now that the query sometimes(looks random) need around 5-15 seconds to execute.
I just wrote a while loop and let it run 10x10 times total 100 times.
around 60 was under 1 second 20 was under 5 seconds and all other was bigger than 5 seconds.

So My question is: is this query taking so long because the table is getting bigger and bigger? Why does the execution time changes so hard?

Edit: In phpmayadmin this query is exequtet in under 0.001 seconds every time

Comment: If you run the query quickly multiple times the server is just going to cache the result for a bit, but sometimes the table changes and it has to re-calculate everything for you. Also how about using COUNT(id) instead not sure whether using the * was a mythical performance hit.

Comment: hey @Recct i tryed it with COUNT(id) same result for now, tanks for your quick recommendation

Comment: How defragmented is your database? How often do you rebuild your indexes? You should try to stay under 10% fragmented a week and rebuild weekly for optimal performance. Also the answer below is great advice. You should index on a smaller data type

Answer (score 2):

I would think that your `GROUP BY handle` is the problem. How big can the field get and do you have an index on it? Check here for indices on text columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html.

A possible solution would be to add a column where you store for example a sha1 hash of the `handle` column. That will have a fixed width so you can easily add an index - and `GROUP BY` - on that. Then use `EXPLAIN` to see where you can improve more.

Comment: i used a FULLTEXT INDEX on the "handle" field. Like listet in your example. google refferer get stored inside that "handle" field to so they get realy long

Comment: @BurakTopal I don't think that a full-text index is useful for grouping, but you'd have to try a prefixed index to see the difference.

Comment: even if i dont group i have over 1 sec execution time :( i need the full-text index for some search fields that are bind to the handle field. I only could use a "prefixed index" with a length of 150-300 and i dont think that the search will be clean than but i will try

Comment: tested with a prefixed index(150) and this time it even take longer than with the full-text index. is there any other solution i cant search for a string in a sha1 hash

Comment: @BurakTopal The hash is not for full-text searching, you can still use the other column for that. The hash is only for indexing and grouping.